# Endomorphismensatz for Lie superalgebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, lie-superalgebras

For semisimple complex Lie algebras there is Soergel's Endomorphismensatz

$$C = \operatorname{End}(P(w_0)) \cong \mathbf C[\mathfrak h]/\mathbf C[\mathfrak h]^W$$

for $w_0$ the longest element in the Weyl group $W$, and the Struktursatz which says that the functor

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb V: \mathcal O_0 &\longrightarrow \operatorname{Mod-End}(P(w_0)),\\
M &\longmapsto \operatorname{Hom}(P(w_0), M)
\end{aligned}$$

is fully faithful on projectives.

**Question:** Is there a similar statement for Lie superalgebras? I know that [this paper](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~brundan/papers/supero.pdf), thm. 4.5 give a super-generalization for the Struktursatz. However, is there also an equivalent of the Endomorphismensatz?

Answer (score 4):

Certainly, there's nothing as clean as Soergel's statement.  The issue, as alluded to in the paper of Brundan you link is that there isn't just one anti-dominant highest weight in a given block of category O; there can be infinitely many.  Thus, C must be replaced by a much bigger sum of projectives for the Endomorphismensatz to hold.  In fact, if you look at an atypical block for $\mathfrak{gl}(1|1)$, every highest weight is anti-dominant, so the Endomorphismensatz only holds if you take with a projective that has every indecomposable projective as a summand!

Comment: I see that the paper states that I have to take all anti-dominant projectives into account. However, I'd like to relate the endomorphisms of such a projective to $\mathbf C[\mathfrak h]$ or a quotient thereof. Is that possible, as in the non-super case?